# Mouse pointer disappears when moving over the Virtualbox guest terminal? Why?

Tags: virtualbox, terminal, mouse, fedora-22

When I move the mouse pointer over the windows it disappears from that windows? What if I need to copy dome text from the guest terminal?
Also, I cannot Use the menu key in the guest terminal in order to copy and paste commands.

Host: Fedora 22
Guest: Ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox guest additions on the guest ? https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `VirtualBox Guest Additions`. The same thing happens with VMWare Player and other software alike. Without the Guest Additions, you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to switch your mouse from your host OS to the guest OS.

By installing Guest Additions, this allows your mouse to be used normally, copy folders/files from the host OS to the guest OS, etc.

You can install this by clicking on `Devices > Install Guest Additions`

If that option isn't available, try typing `yum install dkms` in the terminal.